# Call priority of type-constrained generic functions in swift?

Tags: swift, generics, swift5

I have the definitions:

```swift
    func compare<T>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool where T: Equatable {
        return lhs == rhs
    }
    
    func compare<T>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool where T: AnyObject {
        return lhs === rhs
    }
    
    func compare<T>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
```

When I call `compare` on an reference type object that also conforms to `Equatable`, how does the compiler decide which of these functions to call?

**A full accepted answer would be link to official swift manifesto explaining how the priority is done, especially when the generic conforms to two different protocols that both have specializations**

Comment: Why don't you call `compare` and inspect which one got called?

Comment: Probably `Equatable` will have priority over `AnyObject` and `AnyObject` will have priority over the generic if the object is a class. I think the order you have there is exactly the priority you would expect.

Comment: a bit more info in this blog post: https://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/10/26/which-function-does-swift-call-part-4-generics/... general rule of thumb is that a more specific overload takes priority

Comment: @NewDev, but it is not clear whether `AnyObject` or `Equatable` are more specific, as non-object types can also conform to Equatable, which means their set difference is not null (that is to say, neither is the subset of the other)

Comment: @WinstonDu, `Equatable` is considered more specific than `AnyObject`.. probably because conformance to `AnyObject` is implicit... the main point is that this is determined at compile-time, and because of sometimes hard-to-see differences, it's best to be careful and not to abuse overloading

Answer (score 1):

For whatever reason, it's not ambiguous to the compiler (I consider this a bug; see below for the error I'd expect), but it is to us. So write an overload to clarify the behavior!

```swift
func compare<T: AnyObject>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
  lhs === rhs
}

func compare<T: AnyObject & Equatable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
  compare(lhs: lhs as AnyObject, rhs: rhs)
}

func compare<T: Equatable>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
  lhs == rhs
}

func compare<T>(lhs: T, rhs: T) -> Bool {
  false
}
```

```swift
protocol ModuleName_A { }
protocol ModuleName_B { }

func ƒ<A: ModuleName_A>(_: A) { }
func ƒ<B: ModuleName_B>(_: B) { }

struct S: ModuleName_A & ModuleName_B { }

ƒ(S()) // Ambiguous use of 'ƒ'
```